# test an API deployed on AWS EC2 whithout using http traffic

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, security, amazon-ec2, ssh

For security reasons I can't add the http traffic to my EC2 machine security group, 
I have only the SSH port open
So I'm looking for some solutions to be able to test my API deplyed on AWS-EC2 using only the PORT22, my server is running on : http://ec2xxxxxx:5000/test

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Port forward your http traffic over your ssh connection?

Answer (score 0):

If you SSH tunnel you would basically test as if you are using localhost. If you have security concerns, maybe best option is to run additinal micro instance in same VPC (would work in classic as well, more variations possible from internal up to full blown external ip, depending on your security concerns)  and allow ONLY it’s IP on port 5000. That way you can test HTTP properly without really worrying about opening main instance to world... sorry for typos, writting from a phone...

Comment: this machine is linked with a bastion instance, and i don't have right to create a machine

Comment: In that case, I’m afraid that your options are fairly limited and boil down to testing on localhost (tunneling or testing from Docker container on same host is more or less equal to it) which is lacking some important checks like firewall setup etc...